# Как нарисовать семицветную радугу дугами в python через simple draw

Tags: python, simple-draw

```py
import simple_draw as sd
    
sd.resolution = (1200, 600)

rainbow_colors = (sd.COLOR_RED, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, sd.COLOR_YELLOW, 
sd.COLOR_GREEN, sd.COLOR_CYAN, sd.COLOR_BLUE, sd.COLOR_PURPLE)

def bubble(point, step):
    radius = 500
    for _ in range(7):
        radius += step
        for i in range(len(rainbow_colors)):
            sd.circle(center_position=point, radius=radius, color=rainbow_colors[i], width=4)
        
for _ in range(7):
point = sd.get_point(550, 50)
step = 5
bubble(point=point, step=step)

sd.pause()
```

радуга получается только последнего цвета из данного списка

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble(point, step):
    radius = 500
    for i in range(len(rainbow_colors)):
        radius += 5
        sd.circle(center_position=point, radius=radius, color=rainbow_colors[i], width=4)

for _ in range(7):
    point = sd.get_point(550, 50)
    step = 5
    bubble(point=point, step=step)
```

Я разобрался. Спасибо за внимание!